# I found an error during the npm run build

Tags: node.js, vue.js, npm, nuxt.js

[image]

I uploaded the nuxt project to the linux server through git, followed by 'npm upgrade nuxt' and then 'npm run build'. However, I encountered an error while building. What should I do?

Here is my error code

```
 FATAL  Nuxt build error                                                                                                                             00:42:06

  at WebpackBundler.webpackCompile (node_modules/@nuxt/webpack/dist/webpack.js:5309:21)
  at <anonymous>
  at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:182:7)


   ╭─────────────────────────────╮
   │                             │
   │   ✖ Nuxt Fatal Error        │
   │                             │
   │   Error: Nuxt build error   │
   │                             │
   ╰─────────────────────────────╯

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! all_find@1.0.0 build: `nuxt build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the all_find@1.0.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

Comment: What did you run / execute to produce this error?

Comment: Can you describe what you mean by _"I put the nuxt project on the linux server"_? Please outline the steps required to reproduce this error

Comment: I uploaded it to the Linux server through git, and that's the screen that I ran on the Linux server! After I uploaded the project, I upgraded the nuxt, and then I did 'npm run build'.

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58478533/edit) and provide exact steps. How did you _"upload through git"_? What does _"upgraded the nuxt"_ mean? What commands did you run? Did you install all your project dependencies with `npm install`?

Comment: I downloaded the project from local to server under the 'git pull' command.
I ran both 'npm upgrade nuxt' and 'npm instal'l. I've corrected the question. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is a nvm version issue. update it to the latest version and you will be through this issue